# How to restrict administrators and users run programs from system drive?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

i need a way to forbid 'everyone' from running programs on drive where windows resides. Any step-by-step ideas?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  What about the built-in tools,  What you want would even prevent launching a command prompt.

Comment: One thing - if you want to restrict people from doing things and changing what they can/can't do, don't make them Administrators!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deny all execute access to the entire system drive, then Windows will have a heck of a time running. :)

You may be better off using Group Policy to setup an application Whitelist.

Check out the `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Run only specified Windows applications` policy specifically, and you'll also want to look into locking down the CMD prompt and Task Manager.

From the help for the above-mentioned policy:

> Limits the Windows programs that users have permission to run on the
>   computer.
>
> If you enable this setting, users can only run programs that you add
>   to the List of Allowed Applications.
>
> This setting only prevents users from running programs that are
>   started by the Windows Explorer process. It does not prevent users
>   from running programs such as Task Manager, which are started by the
>   system process or by other processes. Also, if users have access to
>   the command prompt, Cmd.exe, this setting does not prevent them from
>   starting programs in the command window that they are not permitted to
>   start by using Windows Explorer.

More info [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/) and [here](http://lifehacker.com/5442636/create-an-application-whitelist-in-windows-7).